# Convert JSON to byte array in C

Tags: c, json

I am new to JSON and jansson . I am trying to create a message in JSON using jansson library and send using UDP. Which requires in byte array. Buffer and length of message in bytes. I tried with json_object_size(). But it returns only number of elements in object.Please suggest me a way forward.

```
json_t *messagebody = json_object();
json_object_set_new(messagebody, "request_id", request_id);
json_object_set_new(messagebody, "process_id",  json_string(process_id)); 
json_object_set_new(messagebody, "process_server_id", json_string(process_server_id));  
json_object_set_new(messagebody, "ip_address", json_string(my_ip_address));
json_object_set_new(messagebody, "action", action);
```

Comment: A C string  is a "byte array". Cast the string name to an unsigned char *, and check whether the length is strlen() or strlen() +1 depending on whether receiver expects the nul.

Comment: Wow the jansson document is redicuous the main example spends 99% of its time talking about git, and there is no example about building and output your own JSON, just extracting other peoples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just call `char *json_dumps(const json_t *json, size_t flags)`.

That will give you a char * to a null terminated string representing the encoded json data. You have to free it after you are finished with it. To get the length in bytes you should simply be able to use strlen() on the result.

The flags are explained in API reference under 'encoding'.